# Align JButton icon to the left and keep text centered

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to set up a JButton so that it's icon is aligned to the left of it, while the text is centered.

I have found how to have one of them left, the other right, or both at the same setting, but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Of course I can always redefine the *paint* methods, but I am looking for a leaner way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to your `JButton`, for example a [Border Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) would help:

You create a `JLabel` with an `Icon` and one with the text "Click me":

```
JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("king.png")));
JLabel clickMe = new JLabel("Click me", SwingConstants.CENTER); //We give it the center alignment so it stays on the center of the label.
```

Then you create your `JButton`, give it the Border Layout and add your components to it on the positions where you want it.

```
button.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
button.add(iconLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
button.add(clickMe, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I gave each label a border so you could see how each label looks like, since the `clickMe` label won't be right in the center of the `JButton` but on the center of its `JLabel`:

[image] [image]

I think it's not a big deal as it's almost imperceptible w/o the borders

[image]

Comment: awesome, thanks ! so would that also display differently when rolled over, pressed, or selected ?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew what you mean by "rolled over"? And with "display differently"? When clicked it will be like any `JButton` being pressed and have the same functionality, all it does is change its appearance

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew I get what you mean with "roll over" but I still don't get what you mean with "display differently" can you clarify?

Comment: I mean that for example, if you look at the "add comment" button on stackoverflow, when you hover on it, the color of the background changes. On a default JButton, there is also an appearance change on hover, or when button is selected with the keyboard. I was wondering whether I would have a change of appearance on hover or selection with the solution you propose.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew I recommend you to ask a new question with a [mcve] where you have this approach in your code and an image example of what you're trying to achieve, otherwise this question will become 2 questions. Also please accept the answer if this solves your original question "Align icon on left of button and keep text centered in it"